# Does an Email Service accept Emails sent by phpmailer?

Tags: apex, apex-email-service

I have issues setting up an Email Service which should receive Email sent by an web-form using phpmailer.

Now I've configured it like this:

[image]

I've set **no restriction** to "Accept Email From" in order to receive emails form any sender with no restrictions. It works flawlessly, when I send the email via Gmail or other SMTP-accounts for testing.

Only when the email is sent via phpmailer the email is bouncing with this error-email:

> An error occured while trying to deliver the attached email. You may
>   wish to report the following information to the owner of
>   application@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.salesforce.com.
>
> SenderAuthorization: noreply@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.com is not authorized to
>   send emails to this service.
>
> ---
>
> The attached email could not be processed because:
>
> noreply@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.com is not authorized to send emails to this
>   service.
>
> Reporting-MTA: dns; PLACEHOLDER_ONLY-app1-5-par.ops.sfdc.net
>
> Final-Recipient: rfc822; application@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.salesforce.com
>   Action: failed Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 551 SenderAuthorization:
>   noreply@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.com is not authorized to send emails to this
>   service. Status: 5.5.1

The source of the bounced email looks like this

```
Return-Path: <noreply@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.com>
Received: from zion.PLACEHOLDER.xx ([85.10.192.17]) by mx.kundenserver.de (mxeue111
 [217.72.192.67]) with ESMTPS (Nemesis) id 1MwPP1-1di6n91Ukn-00s88g for
 <heim@elastify.eu>; Mon, 26 Jun 2017 14:50:50 +0200
Received: from zion.PLACEHOLDER.xx (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by zion.PLACEHOLDER.xx (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-4+deb7u1) with ESMTP id v5QComLb003139;
    Mon, 26 Jun 2017 14:50:48 +0200
Received: (from www-data@localhost)
    by zion.PLACEHOLDER.xx (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id v5QComeL003138;
    Mon, 26 Jun 2017 14:50:48 +0200
X-Authentication-Warning: zion.PLACEHOLDER.xx: www-data set sender to noreply@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.com using -f
To: application@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.com,
        application@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.salesforce.com,
        heim@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.eu, ivan.petrov@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.com
Subject: HR | Job Application for PLACEHOLDER
X-PHP-Originating-Script: 1000:class.phpmailer.php
Date: Mon, 26 Jun 2017 12:50:48 +0000
From: PLACEHOLDER_ONLY <noreply@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.com>
Reply-To: recruiting@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.com
Message-ID: <ee21ecef74891cc19d04edac3323a3fe@test.microsites.at>
X-Mailer: PHPMailer 5.2.16 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Envelope-To: <heim@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.eu>
X-UI-Filterresults: notjunk:1;V01:K0:AwEERfu+LPw=:ndp9CtAKinq+CjVU3ZT0lBqe4R
 Vg3V9VoeoIuAb694cSTHlHlByHLrxCu3y6cDKcxpC4zkwXPwxkr0jVJYUcfclAwKgvEAX3t8g
 rgmGNEdiN9aL/S+sr5V87FEFVwdxfWnUAk+X1+CQBEzN6DAWA49nEbRFnRhVRznZbyprkFmME
 kO/fEhq3v8lPiM7BUVl3Jb7imwgMNELJhNGZtsYosXXrB6WU7bgvcKwtdeqbMFsD9CT2K7jqC
 QivhI4dFb1trWvfXg8xf8bl/jXDcWg/ndIZL7G7VhFODk3Hg9aDI345uFHmTOH6fOKVGPwI4F
 Jops2OiMDDk+ZPcUvJ2hMxNfYvv1eSjGseoOBzDkBwyseg8Q6EPuRtFO5dd9an/yz4+7hVe8Z
 Ur+xQHcSpZ8kvOTv6UM1YnXB5/+/uFx1J30qW56gQHKAcwA9Pvm8Xlc35+30poV1qEP/Qvu36
 /XwTL62msNUH17fDWyWdPQl9QYiA5b97odAE7lj4A7c86FePJchiSDO03pHyNPFNrKfE0uWs/
 Wl+6/GNtZHsbIR/XFv3U5VpWRJeSEOJQEZfEU2j/fil9n8upAMx830NMzEyGm9/ffwVaBx0ci
 kSpkip8R3rrDev/8cXUD+T1S62yhydS+/4VC8Ma/keN6Nw16xqdWMbm87dcX+g9MgqsgBsWtE
 iqXxq01E/9WtFn8eDMM94ygg8nm0DZhu8XTqz4v2CuT/mD8kIi7uFc6x8YePXIX4c2Hx+kyu2
 inUv6KCSYmYnruIOhWiEx5zaqOSeHo7aNIcT7MupE1O2i8zlwewsO13JrSvTcL9J3Q2F6CLlw
 +vymq6EW3tWh3P1piej0qzLQuF+lYukLgWmQJvEBYZuq9vL6ShZ3BI97Dh4OhGPuFtZbBVZhp
 YUIOIBYnlaInUgHE9Hc09WAMvjdvkgR3WyalfzOGkcWDtkekUyYP5rdFRWNJAavlrHWmobbuv
 /ptggGX6cuFE52aSu6LEV2e9MbwQb7kExhdeKkY9XghWOSskgvyVImp3Bon1vRTZEPFOWm6bt
 SUiq6dQ9dTkAcnItsah78MDJGNOH8c1mWaC1Htz2aqKBt0FHwnfSrojrfjejcKA54XbTwF3SN
 o03Q6SkRevWPQehr2JlYnKVQ6K1vi6UI4FqlndQb3JT9eDhb3aJ41EfUDZiwWt0rnPEdFQmY9
 oyvR0sXTzkWrTl/yMkfiY9LD4NRn2pJUxYTwYsCxNMNDE6X7dzQu3gObXihfHFNT7cc9YkTbu
 lS2AfG+T2evn+nWLHXVCw+Oz7JddN3Ii1Gw==
```

The source-code of the emails which are working fine and do not bounce looks like this:

```
Reply-To: heim@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.eu
To: application@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.salesforce.com
From: Gerhard Uwe Heim <heim@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.eu>
Subject: HR | Job Application for PLACEHOLDER
Organization: PLACEHOLDER_ONLY GmbH & Co. KG
Message-ID: <480e26d2-0d48-158b-5e2f-7a4dd31f5f34@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.eu>
Date: Mon, 26 Jun 2017 15:55:07 +0200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/52.2.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="------------B10661E725FC67E4F265B57D"
Content-Language: en-US

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--------------B10661E725FC67E4F265B57D
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

  First Name: 333
  Last Name: 444
  Email:heim@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.eu
  Phone: 888888
  Preferred Language: DE



--------------B10661E725FC67E4F265B57D
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
  <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  </head>
  <body text="#000000" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <pre wrap="">
 First Name: 333
 Last Name: 444
 Email: <a class="moz-txt-link-abbreviated" href="mailto:heim@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.eu">heim@PLACEHOLDER_ONLY.eu</a>
 Phone: 888888
 Preferred Language: DE

</pre>
  </body>
</html>

--------------B10661E725FC67E4F265B57D--
```

Comment: When you edit the email address, is the Accept Email From box empty?

Comment: @DanielHoechst - yes, it's empty now, but I also have tried to set the email address explicitly to the one salesforce is complaining about - it does NOT HELP. So I'm pretty sure it is not related to the sender, but to phpmailer and some headers it sets in the email. Phpmailer is famous for spamming and blocked by a lot of services. The error is very misleading, though. We are now trying to use SMTP instead...